# No rinse sanitisor available in the UK?

Tags: sanitation, sanitizer

Looking a good, no rinse sanitisor readily available in the UK

Something like the highly recommended [Star San](http://www.northernbrewer.com/shop/star-san.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StarSan looks like it's available [in your area](http://www.the-home-brew-shop.co.uk/acatalog/Five_Star_Chemicals.html).  I use their sanitizer and it works great!  As they say, "don't fear the foam!"